# Detect when any process in executing in zsh script?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

Is there a means to determine whether the zsh shell is currently executing (any) process? I'd like to bind a key only when the terminal prompt is not available (i.e. a process is currently executing within it so the user cannot execute new commands). This is for accessibility purposes.

So, for example, if I have a blank prompt:

`zork@macbook $`, pressing `x` does nothing.

But if I have a long running process like a dev server:

`zork@macbook $ serve localhost:3000`

I could bind the key `x` to `ctrl+C`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: _determine whether the zsh shell is currently executing (any) process_ : `ps` can be used to generate a list of all processes. From this you could pick the ones you are interested in.  `pidof` may be even more convenient. Of course, both approaches identify the process by name, i.e. you have to assume that each zsh process is started under the name `zsh`. However, I don't undderstand the rest of your question, i.e. the part related to the terminal prompt.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `serve localhost:3000`, `serve` becomes the foreground process with which your terminal interacts, instead of the Zsh line editor (ZLE). So, at this point, the ZLE can no longer handle your keybindings. Instead, you will have to process the keystrokes inside `serve`.